# Is it possible for a client to have a very old Salesforce version?

Tags: org, developer-org

I believe that Salesforce will auto-upgrade all the orgs once a new version is released. But just very recently my colleague showed me his org which looks quite old. I believe it was created in 2008 or even before. The look and feel was very different from nowadays Salesforce org(not the Salesforce classic and lightning different). So is it possible to have a very old Salesforce org?

Comment: I would think it all depends on if they have enabled the new features or not. i.e **"Enable the Salesforce Classic 2010 User Interface Theme"**. FYI you can turn it on and off if you want a flash back. But do it in a sandbox as it disables chatter, etc so not sure of the implications of doing it in production. Not sure if this is a complete answer so putting it as a comment for now

Comment: yep - I'm managing a client org right now that is Salesforce 2010 classic; they never cared for Chatter and like things the way they are. At least it isn't a 3270-style UI.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is certainly possible to have a Salesforce Org that is visually "old".

Here is a screenshot from a circa 2009 testing Org that we mostly interact with via the API. No one really logs into the UI to do updates etc...

[image]

Not meaning to sound like I've drunk too much Salesforce Kool-Aid, but this is one of the generally well done areas of Salesforce. I can still interact with this org from the APIs using anything up to v37.0 and it will work. There are exceptions (and bugs) to that statement, but by and large it just works. The underlying APIs have been updated to the latest version even though the UI is still from 2008.

---

You can see details about the UI themes in the APIs - [User Interface Themes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner_themes.htm)

> Two user interface themes match the earlier iterations of Salesforce.
>
> - Theme3—The “Salesforce Classic 2010 user interface theme.” This interface was previously referred to as “Salesforce” or “new user interface theme.” You might also be familiar with it as the Salesforce Aloha interface.
> - Theme2—The “Salesforce Classic 2005 user interface theme.” This interface was previously referred to as “Salesforce Classic” or the “classic user interface theme.”

---

As per Eric's comment of toggling the Classic 2010 UI Theme via

App Setup > Customize > User Interface > Enable the Salesforce Classic 2010 User Interface Theme

[image]